# SQL Database Schema Design For Large 3 Billion Relationship Database

Tags: sql, performance

Get your geek on.  Can you solve this?

I am designing a products database for SQL Server 2008 R2 Ed. (not Enterprise Ed.) that will be used to store custom product configurations for over 30,000 distinct products.  The database will have up to 500 users at a time.

**Here is the design problem…**

Each Product has a collection of Parts (up to 50 parts per product).
So if I have 30,000 Products and each of them can have up to 50 Parts, that’s 1.5 million distinct Product-to-Part relationships

```
                                  …or as an equation…
```

**30,000 (Products) X 50 (Parts) = 1.5 million Product-to-Parts records.**

…and If…

Each Part can have up to 2000 finish options (A finish is a paint color).

*NOTE: Only one finish will be selected by a user at run-time.  The 2000 finish options I need to store are the allowed options for a specific part on a specific product.*

So if I have 1.5 million distinct product-to-part relationships/records and each of those parts can have up to 2,000 finishes that is 3 billion allowable product-to-part-to finish relationships/records

```
                                  …or as an equation…
```

**1.5 million (Parts) x 2,000 (Finishes) = 3 Billion Product-to-Part-to-Finishes records.**

How can I design this database so that I can execute **fast and efficient queries** for a specific product and return its list of Parts and all the allowable Finishes for each part without 3 Billion Product-to-Part-to-Finish records?  Read time is more important then write time.

Please post your thoughts/suggestions if you have experience with large databases.

Thanks!

Comment: I assume parts do not all have the same colors/finishes to choise from?

Comment: If you have 2K distinct paint choises for _each part_ of which there are 50 to choose; I would not wonder if the end-users will be overwhelmed (kidding)

Comment: When I go to the store they usually only have t-shirts in maybe 5 colors... There's a reason for this.

Comment: Yes Mark, some of the parts may share finishes and others may not.

Comment: Nishant - The 2K distinct paint choices for each part are filtered down based on questions that the customer answers as they build their product online.  The database is just storing the possible configurations for the product.  I need to be able to query the finish options quickly.  We don't show the customer everything at once.  Good comment.

Answer (score 6):

Why is this even remotely challenging? If there is one thing relational databases are good at, that would be **exactly** the problem you describe: 3 tables and 2 many-to-many relations. The number '3 billion' only comes up if some runaway full cartezian join is left to run. Just do the very basic, normalized design:

```
:setvar dbname test
:setvar PRODUCTSCOUNT 30000
:setvar PARTSCOUNT 5000
:setvar FINISHESCOUNT 2000
:setvar PRODUCTSPARTS 50
:setvar PARTFINISHES 1

use master;
set nocount on;
go

rollback
go

:on error exit

if db_id('$(dbname)') is not null
begin
    alter database [$(dbname)] set single_user with rollback immediate;
    drop database [$(dbname)];
end 
go

create database [$(dbname)] 
    on (name = test_data, filename='c:\temp\test.mdf', size = 10GB)
    log on (name = test_log, filename='c:\temp\test.ldf', size = 100MB);
go

use [$(dbname)];
go

create table Products (
    Product_Id int not null identity(0,1) primary key,
    Description varchar(256));
go      

create table Parts (
    Part_Id int not null identity(0,1) primary key,
    Description varchar(256));

create table Finishes (
    Finish_Id smallint not null identity(0,1) primary key,
    Description varchar(256));

create table ProductParts (
    Product_Id int not null,
    Part_Id int not null,
    constraint fk_products_parts_product
        foreign key (Product_Id)
        references Products (Product_Id),
    constraint fk_product_parts_part 
        foreign key (Part_Id)
        references Parts (Part_Id),
    constraint pk_product_parts
        primary key (Product_Id, Part_Id));

create table PartFinishes (
    Part_Id int not null,
    Finish_Id smallint not null,
    constraint fk_part_finishes_part
        foreign key (Part_Id)
        references Parts (Part_Id),
    constraint fk_part_finishes_finish
        foreign key (Finish_Id)
        references Finishes (Finish_Id),
    constraint pk_part_finishes
        primary key (Part_Id, Finish_Id));
go      

-- populate Products
declare @cnt int = 0, @description varchar(256);
begin transaction;
while @cnt < $(PRODUCTSCOUNT)
begin
    set @description = 'Product ' + cast(@cnt as varchar(10));
    insert into Products (Description) values (@description);
    set @cnt += 1;
    if @cnt % 1000 = 0
    begin
        commit;
        raiserror (N'Inserted %d products', 0,1, @cnt);
        begin transaction;
    end
end
commit;
raiserror (N'Done. %d products', 0,1, @cnt);
go

-- populate Parts
declare @cnt int = 0, @description varchar(256);
begin transaction;
while @cnt < $(PARTSCOUNT)
begin
    set @description = 'Part ' + cast(@cnt as varchar(10));
    insert into Parts (Description) values (@description);
    set @cnt += 1;
    if @cnt % 1000 = 0
    begin
        commit;
        raiserror (N'Inserted %d parts', 0,1, @cnt);
        begin transaction;
    end
end
commit;
raiserror (N'Done. %d parts', 0,1, @cnt);
go

-- populate Finishes
declare @cnt int = 0, @description varchar(256);
begin transaction;
while @cnt < $(FINISHESCOUNT)
begin
    set @description = 'Finish ' + cast(@cnt as varchar(10));
    insert into Finishes (Description) values (@description);
    set @cnt += 1;
    if @cnt % 1000 = 0
    begin
        commit;
        raiserror (N'Inserted %d finishes', 0,1, @cnt);
        begin transaction;
    end
end
raiserror (N'Done. %d finishes', 0,1, @cnt);
commit;
go

-- populate product parts
declare @cnt int = 0, @parts int = 0, @part int, @product int = 0;
begin transaction;
while @product < $(PRODUCTSCOUNT)
begin
    set @parts = rand() * ($(PRODUCTSPARTS)-1) + 1;
    set @part = rand() * $(PARTSCOUNT);     
    while 0 < @parts 
    begin
        insert into ProductParts (Product_Id, Part_Id)
            values (@product, @part);
        set @parts -= 1;
        set @part += rand()*10+1;
        if @part >= $(PARTSCOUNT)
            set @part = rand()*10;
        set @cnt += 1;
        if @cnt % 1000 = 0
        begin
            commit;
            raiserror (N'Inserted %d product-parts', 0,1, @cnt);
            begin transaction;
        end
    end
    set @product += 1;
end
commit;
raiserror (N'Done. %d product-parts', 0,1, @cnt);
go      

-- populate part finishes
declare @cnt int = 0, @part int = 0, @finish int, @finishes int;
begin transaction;
while @part < $(PARTSCOUNT)
begin
    set @finishes = rand() * ($(PARTFINISHES)-1) + 1;
    set @finish = rand() * $(FINISHESCOUNT);
    while 0 < @finishes 
    begin
        insert into PartFinishes (Part_Id, Finish_Id)
            values (@part, @finish);
        set @finish += rand()*10+1;
        if @finish >= $(FINISHESCOUNT)
            set @finish = rand()*10+1;
        set @finishes -= 1;
        set @cnt += 1;
        if @cnt % 1000 = 0
        begin
            commit;
            raiserror (N'Inserted %d part-finishes', 0,1, @cnt);
            begin transaction;
        end
    end
    set @part += 1;
end
commit;
raiserror (N'done. %d part-finishes', 0,1, @cnt);
go
```

Now if we run this through a basic test, the results are pretty good:

```
set statistics time on;
set statistics io on;

declare @product int = rand()*30000;
select *
from Products po
join ProductParts pp on po.Product_Id = pp.Product_Id
join Parts pa on pa.Part_Id = pp.Part_Id
join PartFinishes pf on pf.Part_Id = pa.Part_Id
join Finishes f on pf.Finish_id = f.Finish_Id
where po.Product_Id = @product;
```

Execution times:

```
(33 row(s) affected)
Table 'Finishes'. Scan count 0, logical reads 66, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Parts'. Scan count 0, logical reads 66, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'PartFinishes'. Scan count 33, logical reads 66, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'ProductParts'. Scan count 1, logical reads 3, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Products'. Scan count 0, logical reads 2, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

 SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 0 ms,  elapsed time = 5 ms.
```

That is 5ms execution time for a random product. And this is nowhere near a 'server', I'm running this on my laptop. No surprises there, all accesses are covered by the clustered indexes on those tables. I'll let you set up a stress test with 500 users and measure for yourself how it performs under concurrency. I expect it to hold up quite nicely.

Comment: +1 for everything. The "laptop trick" is an awesome way of showing potential :)

Comment: +1 for such an awesome answer. I really learned some basics. Thanks @Remus Rusanu

Comment: Agreed.  This is a pretty modest database where the largest table contains 30,000 rows.  There is no table, and no reasonable result set, that will have anywhere near 3 billion records.

Answer (score 3):

First off, 3 Billion is an upper bound.  Most likely you'll have a lot fewer real world combinations.  That said...

The number one thing here is to have good indexes.

The second thing is to have enough ram in the server (and cpu power) to handle the types of queries you might be doing.

So, what are your queries going to be like?

My guess is that your products are going to be grouped / classified in some way.

If this is an ordering system then this means queries at that level will probably only return maybe a few hundred products at a time.

After product selection, you'll load things like associated parts for the selected product(s).  Again, this will result in less than 50 records returned per product.  Quite small.  The amount of data for finish types aren't that great either.

Even if this is just a reference system the amount of data being utilized in any one query isn't that great.

So really what we're left with is just physical storage and RAM.  The physical storage will have to be large enough to store the data.  Probably on the order of a 1GB or so; which is still pretty small.

For RAM you'll want enough to let SQL server keep the relevant tables in memory.  If the physical size is about right then I'd say a 8GB system is just fine with maybe a quad processor depending on load.  They're cheap, so have two.

You mention 500 users, but what are the work load types of those users?  Are they all on constantly at the same time?  How often are they querying the server?  How much data do they need at once?

These questions will lead you to figuring out the actual number of queries per second (and the type) that the DB hardware will need to support.

As a side note, your calculations are way off.  As an example, you shouldn't multiply the total number of finish options by the total number of products/parts.  I seriously doubt that there exists any part with 2000 paint color choices.

A better way of calculating this out is going to be to see what the MEAN number of finish options a part has times the MEAN number of parts a given product has.  Then you'll have a closer idea to the number of possible combinations.  But that's just a useless data point as this number really has little meaning given the potential queries anyway...

Comment: Based on my calculations we will have 3 Billion Product-to-Part-to-Finishes records currently. So are you saying that I can have a table with 3 Billion records in it and it will be fast if I have the right indexes /hardware?  It sounds like we have enough hardware.  BTW...it's 500 concurrent users.

Comment: @K-Bell: First off, I'm saying that you won't have a table with 3 billion records in it based on the data you provided.  It's going to be much sparser than that.  Second, yes, it will be fast with the right indexes and hardware.  We have a couple sql server databases with literally 300 times that amount in it now covering nearly a terrabyte of physical storage.  SQL Server itself can handle this amount of data just fine.  Just not an a Pentium 4 ;)

Comment: Where did you come up with 16TB database size limit? The very link you provided mentions: `Database size: 524,272 terabytes`. 16TB is a single **data file** size limit. You should know better...

Comment: @Remus: Yes, yes I should :)  oops.  Let's try this again.  Max DB size is beyond huge: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Index the columns that are going to be queried against.
2. If it's like `80:20 :: read:write` use caching e.g. MemcacheD

Comment: Every database is 95:5. An update has a where = read. An insert checks duplicates = read first. 5% is massive write volumes in practice...

Comment: Sure it was, before Twitter, but obviously we are not talking about Twitter kind of app, plus twitter uses NoSQL for that.

Comment: gbn is correct; almost all LOB databases are heavy reads and this is ignoring twitter/fb/google.

Comment: @Chris: yes agree. And hence, bullet #2 stands true. :)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to go object-relational or nested-relational, so that the ids of the parts that comprise the assembly are contained within the assembly record, rather than being linked to the assembly via an intermediary table.

Answer (score 0):

@Remus design will work well, but you will need to partition table on some columns. It will speed up the queries. You can easily archive with switch statement if it is on partition.

Even if you have Index seek on all procs, it can still be slower for large number of rows without partition. You can use product code or something that will tell you this is a new product or old based on some naming convention. You can include this partition column in queries and it will be fast.

Importing lots of data to these table are also problem. You need to think about which indexes to rebuild after insert and timing of that. If you add data to new partition, performance will be acceptable.